# Show a solution of E-L is in fact minimizing

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

This is an exercise in Cartan's *Differential Forms*:

> If $f(t,x,y)$ satisfies $$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial t\partial y}-y\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial x\partial y}=0$$
>   and $f$ is convex as a function of $y$, then $$\int_a^bf(t,x,x')dt\ge\int_a^bf(t,X,X')dt$$
>   where $x(t)$ and $X$(t) has the same endpoint and $X$ is straight line as a graph.

It is easy to see $X$ is an extremum directly from the Euler-Lagrange equation, but I have no clue how to show $X$ is minimal from that convex condition.

Comment: A hint: A convex functions satisfies $f(y_1)-f(y_2)\geq Df(y_2)(y_1-y_2)$. Can you somehow plug in this inequality using that $Df(y_2)=0$ (whcih you know from the Euler Lagrange equation)?

Comment: @F.Conrad What is $D$ here?

Comment: I denote by $Df$ the derivative of $f$ w.r.t to its arguments.

Comment: @F.Conrad All of its arguments? something like $Df = [\frac{\partial f}{\partial t},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}]$?